# MySQL Indexes: What is Size field in Indexes?

Tags: mysql

What is the Size field in Indexes and how it works?

[image]

Comment: _MySQL can use indexes on columns more efficiently if they are declared as the same type and size. In this context, VARCHAR and CHAR are considered the same if they are declared as the same size. For example, VARCHAR(10) and CHAR(10) are the same size, but VARCHAR(10) and CHAR(15) are not._ [mysql ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you create an index, you can specify that only a prefix of the value should be included in the index. This is the size of the index. It's optional for most datatypes, but required for `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns. It's also needed for any column if its length exceeds the limit on index size; for instance, InnoDB's index size limit is 767 bytes for some table formats; if you want to index a `VARCHAR(1023)` column, you'll need to specify a prefix size less than 768.

See [Column Prefix Key Parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes)

Answer (score 1):

This is how much of the value will be uniquely indexed. You can index the whole value on a one-to-one basis, or you can index just a prefix which might put multiple values into one bucket. This is a performance/space trade off.

Here is a simplified example.

If you were to create an index with a single character...

```
create table animals (
    name varchar(255),
    index(name(1))
);
```

That will only index the first character of each name.

```
index       name
----------------
A           Ape
A           Aardvark
A           Ant
A           Anteater
B           Baboon
C           Cat
D           Dog
D           Dingo
```

So when you query `where name = 'Aardvark'` it will use the `A` index to find a list of `Ape, Aardvark, Ant, Anteater` and search it. The index improves the performance of the query, but there's still some searching to do.

Let's say you had `index(name(3))`.

```
index       name
----------------
Ape         Ape
Aar         Aardvark
Ant         Ant
Ant         Anteater
Bab         Baboon
Cat         Cat
Dog         Dog
Din         Dingo
```

Now when you query `where name = 'Aardvark'` it will use the `Aar` index to find just `Aardvark` and will perform fast. But if you search for `where name = 'Ant'` it will use `Ant` to find `Ant, Anteater` and have to search that list.

You need to make the decision between index size and performance that fits your data and queries.

---

A practical example, say I'm storing SHA-1 checksums as text. Those are 40 characters long. But for all practical purposes the first 7 or 8 characters are very, very likely to be unique. So I store all 40 characters, but only index the first 8.

```
checksum char(40),
index(checksum(8))
```

Now `where checksum = '97531bc4cb33c00f3e9ff10d65386b8e96cdae3d'` will use the `97531bc4` index and likely produce a single value. This potentially saves a lot of space without any impact on performance.